# How does rails create a temp database from a yml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following the rails tutorial https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login.

**users.yml**

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.comm
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

**users_login_test.rb**

```html
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "login with valid information" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, params: { session: { email:    @user.email,
                                          password: 'password' } }
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
  end
end
```

1. Through debugging user Michael can log in without signing up because I suspect that **users.yml** became a database, but how did it do that?
2. Is there any way to figure this out through byebug or pry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I suspect that `users.yml` became a database

Close, but not quite. Contents of `users.yml` were inserted in your test database (which is configured in `database.yml`).

This is called [fixtures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures).